# How can i load image from Media Library using UIImagePicker results URL and PHAsset on IOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, phasset

```
PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
for (PHAsset *asset in result) {        
    [manager requestImageForAsset:asset
                       targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize
                      contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault
                          options:requestOptions
                    resultHandler:^void(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info) {
                        _profileImageView.image = image;

                        //[images addObject:_profileImageView];
                    }];    
}
```

its not work for me

Comment: paste info about requestOptions

Comment: PHImageRequestOptions *requestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
        requestOptions.resizeMode   = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
        requestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
        requestOptions.synchronous = true;

Comment: add requestOptions.networkAccessAllowed = YES; and try

Answer (score 0):

First make `requestoptions` like,

```
self.requestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
self.requestOptions.resizeMode   = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
self.requestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;

// this one is key
self.requestOptions.synchronous = true;
```

and if there are multiple assets in an array filled with PHAsset objects, then add this code:

```
self.assets = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:assets];
PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[assets count]];

// assets contains PHAsset objects.
 __block UIImage *ima;

for (PHAsset *asset in self.assets) {
// Do something with the asset

[manager requestImageForAsset:asset
                   targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize
                  contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault
                      options:self.requestOptions
                resultHandler:^void(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info) {
                    ima = image;

                    [images addObject:ima];
                }];


}
```

and now the `images` array contains all the images in `uiimage` format.

Hope this will help :)